# SQL Query to Join Two Tables Based On Closest Timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, timestamp

I need to retrieve the records from dbo.transaction (transaction of all users-more than one transaction for each user) that having timestamp which is closest to the time in  dbo.bal (current balance details of each user-only one record for each user)

ie, the resultant records should equal to the no of records in the dbo.bal

Here i tried the below query, am getting only the records less than the time in dbo.bal. But there are some record having timestamp greater than and closest to dbo.bal.time

```
SELECT dbo.bal.uid,
       dbo.bal.userId,
       dbo.bal.balance,
       dbo.bal.time,
  (SELECT TOP 1 transactionBal
   FROM dbo.transaction
   WHERE TIMESTAMP <= dbo.bal.time
   ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) AS newBal
FROM dbo.bal
WHERE dbo.bal.time IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY dbo.bal.time DESC
```

here is my table structure,

```
dbo.transaction
---------------

| uid| userId   | description| timestamp               | credit | transactionBal
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 101      | buy credit1| 2012-01-25 03:23:31.624 | 100    | 500
| 2  | 102      | buy credit5| 2012-01-18 03:13:12.657 | 500    | 700
| 3  | 103      | buy credit3| 2012-01-15 02:16:34.667 | 300    | 300
| 4  | 101      | buy credit2| 2012-01-13 05:34:45.637 | 200    | 300
| 5  | 101      | buy credit1| 2012-01-12 07:45:21.457 | 100    | 100
| 6  | 102      | buy credit2| 2012-01-01 08:18:34.677 | 200    | 200

dbo.bal
-------

| uid| userId   | balance | time                    |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 101      | 500     | 2012-01-13 05:34:45.645 |
| 2  | 102      | 700     | 2012-01-01 08:18:34.685 |
| 3  | 103      | 300     | 2012-01-15 02:16:34.672 |
```

And the result should be like,

```
| Id | userId   | balance | time                    | credit | transactionBal 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 101      | 500     | 2012-01-13 05:34:45.645 | 200    | 300
| 2  | 102      | 700     | 2012-01-01 08:18:34.685 | 200    | 200
| 3  | 103      | 300     | 2012-01-15 02:16:34.672 | 300    | 300
```

Please help me.. Any help is must appreciated...Thankyou

Comment: also mention the desired resultset from the above two tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful if you posted your table structures, but ...

1. I think your inner query needs a join condition.  (That is not actually in your question)
2. Your `ORDER BY` clause in the inner query could be `ABS(TIMESTAMP - DB0.BAL.TIME)`.  That should give you the smallest difference between the 2.

Does that help ?

Based on the follwing Sql Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a900/15 I came up with ...

```
SELECT 
  bal.uid, 
  bal.userId, 
  bal.balance, 
  bal.time,
  trn.timestamp,
  trn.description,
  datediff(ms, bal.time, trn.timestamp)
FROM 
  money_balances bal
  JOIN money_transaction trn on
    trn.userid = bal.userid and
    trn.uid =
    (
      select top 1 uid
      from money_transaction trn2
      where trn2.userid = trn.userid
      order by abs(datediff(ms, bal.time, trn2.timestamp))
    )
WHERE 
  bal.time IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
  bal.time DESC
```

I cannot vouch for its performance because I know nothing of your data, but I believe it works.

I have simplified my answer - I believe what you need is

```
SELECT 
  bal.uid as baluid,   
  (
      select top 1 uid 
      from money_transaction trn2
      where trn2.userid = bal.userid
      order by abs(datediff(ms, bal.time, trn2.timestamp))
  ) as tranuid
FROM 
  money_balances bal
```

and from that you can derive all the datasets you need.
for example :

```
with matched_credits as
(
SELECT 
  bal.uid as baluid,   
  (
      select top 1 uid 
      from money_transaction trn2
      where trn2.userid = bal.userid
      order by abs(datediff(ms, bal.time, trn2.timestamp))
  ) as tranuid
FROM 
  money_balances bal 
)
select 
  *
from 
  matched_credits mc
  join money_balances mb on
    mb.uid = mc.baluid
  join money_transaction trn on
    trn.uid = mc.tranuid
```

Comment: Can you help me according to first suggestion..? Does this poosible? it is more helpful if you provide the query with inner join.

Comment: We would have to see your tables and some sample data but a solution is definitely available - what you are asking for is not impossible.

Comment: I have updated my question with table structure..Can you check it out?

Comment: I have checked here but, 

     1.i got this error "The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart."
      2. Also it seems that here you considering the 'ms' part for datediff..It may be hours , minits etc (Only condition is timestamp which close to the time)

Comment: 1. I think that is because I had to make a guess at your data types.  Look at Mark's post below - casting to float may be best.

Comment: 2. milliseconds is MORE accurate than seconds/minutes & hours

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27857/discussion-between-lambypie-and-hugh-jones)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT dbo.bal.uid,
       dbo.bal.userId,
       dbo.bal.balance,
       dbo.bal.time,
  (SELECT TOP 1 transactionBal
   FROM dbo.transaction
   ORDER BY abs(datediff(ms, dbo.bal.time, TIMESTAMP))) AS newBal
FROM dbo.bal
WHERE dbo.bal.time IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY dbo.bal.time DESC
```